# Excel: comparing one column to another. When there's a match, copy the adjacent cell

Tags: excel, match, matching

So I have a massive list of product numbers and descriptions. I have some new descriptions for some of the product numbers.

I want to find just those in the massive list that match, then copy the new descriptions into the big list's description field.

I can find the match using:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A7,$C$2:$C$426,1,FALSE)),"FALSE", "File found in row " & MATCH(A7,$C$2:$C$426,0))
```

But beyond that I'm stuck!

Comment: I'm a bit confused - If you want all the descriptions based upon the #s found in the second list, why not just use the second list?? Can you post a small example of what the lists look like?

Comment: @JohnBustos Explained more below, but see a screenshot here [link](http://postimage.org/image/j5mshaxmf/)

Comment: Given your explanation, it's really easy, just do a `Vlookup` for the value in column A from column C and then filter for non error values. does that make sense? would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Create a third column called (say) consolidated list.

```
|product no| existing description| new descriptions|consolidated list
```

Now in the consolidated list column, write a formula:

```
=IF(<check for match>, <if match found, then copy column 3 entry>, <else copy column 2 entry>)
```

Copy the formula in the whole column. Now this column should be the updated column. Replace the existing colum by this column.

Comment: Ah, let me explain a little more.

THere is a long list in column A. And a long list in column C. They do not necessarily correspond.

There are old descriptions in column B, each adjacent to the product number in A.

There are new descriptions in column D, adjacent to product numbers in C.

I want to search the whole of A for any individual entry in C. If there's a match, copy the adjacent (to C) in D to the adjacent (to A) in B.

For example, A1 matches C5. I need D5 copied to B1.

Is that clearer?